# Accessing External Contract's Struct Array mappings

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct

I have struct in an external contract that I need access to

```
Contract Ext{
 Struct user{
    uint dailybalance;
 }
 mapping ( address => user[] ) userDailyBalances;
}
```

How do I access the dailybalance for a specific index in the mapped array of structs?

```
Contract Need{

   function need(){
      Ext x = Ext ( Extcontractaddress );
      uint256 bal = x.userDailyBalances( msg.sender )[0].dailybalance;

  } 
}
```

Does not work nor does
x.userDailyBalances( msg.sender[0].dailybalance )
nor
x.userDailyBalances( msg.sender.[0].dailybalance )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the storage of the external contract directly which is not allowed. Refer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/can-a-contract-access-another-contracts-storage).

You need to have a getter method implemented inside the external contract to make this feasible.

**External Contract:**

```
Contract Ext{
 Struct user{
    uint dailybalance;
 }
 mapping ( address => user[] ) userDailyBalances;

function getDailyBalance(user) constant returns(unit) {
        return userDailyBalances( user )[0].dailybalance;
    }

}
```

**Your Contract:**

```
Contract Need{

   function need(){
      Ext x = Ext ( Extcontractaddress );
      uint256 bal = x.getDailyBalance( msg.sender );

  }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is exactly what I was planning to do.. was just curious if a direct approach was possible

Comment: since the mapping is not initialized yet (declared only), you need to have  setter function as well in the practical scenario.

Comment: I used a getter function in the external; contract and then accessed that instead of the mapping directly