# Use shared library type in contracts

Tags: solc, compilation

I want to reuse on type `DateRange` in two contracts. However, I fail with multiple errors. Currently I have one error:

`G21FE98E9  Member "endTicks" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in tuple(uint64,uint64)`

I didn't find any related info that could help solve this issue.

Here is complete contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract SeasonFactory {    
    address public owner;
    address[] public seasons;

    event SeasonCreated(uint64 indexed beginTicks, uint64 indexed endTicks, address season);

    function SeasonFactory() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function newSeason(uint64 beginTicks, uint64 endTicks) public restricted {
        require(beginTicks < endTicks);
        require(seasons.length == 0 || Season(seasons[seasons.length - 1]).period().endTicks() < beginTicks);

        Season season = new Season(owner, beginTicks, endTicks);
        seasons.push(season);
        emit SeasonCreated(beginTicks, endTicks, season);
    }

    function getSeasonsCount() public view returns(uint) {
        return seasons.length;
    }

    function getSeasonForDate(uint64 ticks) public view returns(address) {
        for (uint i = seasons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Season season = Season(seasons[i]);
            if (ticks >= season.period.beginTicks() && ticks <= season.period.endTicks())
                return season;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    modifier restricted {
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        _;
    }
}

contract Season {
    address public owner;
    SharedTypes.DateRange public period;

    function Season(address owner_, uint64 beginTicks, uint64 endTicks) public {
        owner = owner_;
        period = SharedTypes.DateRange(beginTicks, endTicks);
    }
}

library SharedTypes {
    struct DateRange {    
        uint64 beginTicks;
        uint64 endTicks;
    }
}
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: What is the purpose of `Season(seasons[seasons.length - 1]).period().endTicks() < beginTicks)` and `Season season = Season(seasons[i])` when Season needs 3 parameters?

Comment: Also, if you're inheriting the `Season` function from `contract Season`, you need to place that contract above the `SeasonFactory` and inherit it properly with `contract SeasonFactory is Season {}`

Comment: @ReyHaynes usage with single parameter should be a cast, I guess. I found it somewhere on the internet. There is no inheritance, Factory is obviosly not an object.

Comment: Functions are explicit in use, if it has 3 parameters, you need 3 parameters. You can, however, create multiple functions with the same name and different amount of parameters, which is called [Function Overloading](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html?highlight=overriding#function-overloading)

Comment: I'm just casting some `address` which is known to be a contract T. See https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/interactions-between-contracts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/can-a-contract-access-another-contracts-storage), a contract cannot access another contract's storage directly.

You probably need to implement a getter function, as described in [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26720/accessing-external-contracts-struct-array-mappings).

I tried using the following function in your Season contract and it worked fine:

```
function getTicks(uint ind) view public returns( uint64 ){
    if(ind == 1) return period.endTicks;
    else return period.beginTicks;
}
```

Comment: Yet another solidity surprise. Thank you for an answer.