# Read private variable from different contract in Solidity

Tags: solidity, storage, get-storage-at

I know that if I use the web3 family of libraries, I can use

```
web3.eth.getStorageAt
```

to read any variable I like directly from the storage of a smart contract. Is there a way to do this from a smart contract directly in Solidity as well (without using an Oracle that just runs `web3.eth.getStorageAt`)? I assume not, as that would defeat the purpose of having access modifiers in Solidity at all in my opinion, however just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct - you can only read storage from within your contract. See this for more details

[Can a contract access another contract's storage?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/can-a-contract-access-another-contracts-storage?noredirect=1&lq=1)