# Solidity equivalent of web3.eth.getStorageAt?

Tags: solidity

How can I retrieve the storage value with solidity? I'm looking for something equivalent to `web3.eth.getStorageAt` in web3js.

```
contract WhatEver {
    uint public prize; <-- I want to read this value from another contract
}
```

**EDIT**

The target contract is not owned by me, I'm trying to hack it (one of the Ethernaut levels)

Does anyone know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a contract access another contract's storage?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/can-a-contract-access-another-contracts-storage)

Comment: you can't access storage that way from solidity. but the variable is public so can be access by calling prize() on the contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to get into the mess of accessing raw storage to answer your question. Since the `uint` you're trying to access is `public`, that means there is an externally-facing function called `prize` which returns it, so all your contract would need to do is something like:

```
interface WhatEver {
  function prize() external view returns(uint);
}

contract YourContract {
  function getPrize(address whateverAddress) public view returns(uint) {
    return WhatEver(whateverAddress).prize()
  }
}
```

That being said, this helps you do what you're trying to do, but doesn't answer the question of how to replicate `getStorageAt` in Solidity, so I'd call this only a partial answer.

I do think that you should be able to replicate `getStorageAt` using Yul and maybe a `delegatecall` so that you can `SLOAD` off of the target contract and then read it or return it from memory, but do not know how to do so. (A regular `call` or even `staticcall` may also be sufficient.) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001942/solidity-assembly-read-struct-from-storage-delegatecall) seems to have some of the steps lined up, and makes me believe that the answer may be contingent on the datatype being returned, but unfortunately does not have any answers as of this writing. If you are interested in pursuing this path, [this](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html) page in the Solidity docs explains how storage is used, and [this](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/yul.html#) page has the details for Yul.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a great question.  Can we call an external contract's storage with sload?  As a workaround, I found the vm.load cheatcode with foundry.  I bet if we look at how that code works we'd find the answer.  Do yall know how to do that?